# What's wrong with the code! Text Not Showing! CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm coding in Windows Notepad the following:

[image]

It only display the background in Light Gray, but without showing the heading and the pareagraph!

Comment: http://sscce.org, don't be lazy, please put your code on it.

Comment: You end your style tag with a } instead of a >  on the 9th line

Comment: Thanks NewsAlwaysBetter!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
        <style>
             body {background-color:lightgray}
             h1 {color:blue}
             p {color:green}
        </style> //style tag not end correctly check it
     </head>
     <body>
        <h1>dfgdfd</h1>
        <p>hjsdfkj</p>
     </body>
  </html>
```